# How to show the title in Fragment but hide in the Activity?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I have a `Activity` and it has include more than one `fragment`.

I know it can use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` to hide the title in `Activity`.

But I don't want to hide title for all `fragment`.

Can I hide the title for preference fragment ?

Comment: so that fragment might be a sepearate activity. u can use that fragment as sepearate activity right?

Comment: @Tamilselvan I am not completely understand what you mean , but I think is YES.

Comment: Is there any compulsion to show that preference fragment class u r having as fragment? You can replace that fragment with Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you say, you will have to use more than one activity. For the fragments that are in a same activity, the title bar is either shown or hidden.

Comment: But I only show one fragment one time, can I control which fragment hide the title ?

Comment: Seems there's no reverse call to `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` . A workaround is to use two activities with different theme, say Theme_holo and Theme_noTitleBar. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  We can get actionBar and hide it after setContentView
2. When active fragment, show action bar
3. When fragment detach , notify activity and activity can hide the action bar

Above is my current implement and seems work.  Still testing :-D

Simple sample here - https://bitbucket.org/jimmy64/fragmentsample

Comment: Can you provide a code example? as a new android developer, I don't know how to do what you say.

Comment: Hello, @Matt: <br/>  Please reference below <br/>1 <pre><code> actionBar = this.getActionBar() ; <br/> actionBar.hide() </code></pre>can hide the toolbar <br/>2 Before you show the fragment you can use actionBar.show() to show actionBar and setTitle() of Activity to change the title.  <br/>3 on Fragment , override onDetach , call a method implement in Activity to hide the actionBar again.